# Fill Gaps in Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have an array from this mysql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as opens, HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(open_date)) as hour 
FROM tracking WHERE open_id = 10 GROUP BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(open_date))
```

It allows me to get opens based on every hour. However, there are some gaps in the hours as nothing has been opened at a particular hour. How can I fill the gaps i.e. turn this array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [opens] => 9 [hour] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( [opens] => 2 [hour] => 3 ) )
```

Into:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [opens] => 9 [hour] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( [opens] => 0 [hour] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [opens] => 0 [hour] => 2 ) 
[3] => Array ( [opens] => 2 [hour] => 3 ) )
```

In other words fill missing hours with 0 opens? Can I change my sql query to get this to work or will it have to be via PHP?

Thanks all for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in code based on the results that you get back. One way to do it using only the database would be to have a table (maybe even a temporary one) that contains the hours and do a left outer join on `hours` vs. `tracking`.  Note that this is practical only because the range for `hours` is fixed and relatively small -- basically a single column containing the numbers 0-23.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as opens, hours.hour
FROM hours
LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking ON hours.hour = HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tracking.open_date))
WHERE tracking.open_id = 10
GROUP BY hours.hour
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$aHours = array();

foreach (range(0,23) as $nHour){

    $aHours[] = array('opens' => 0, 'hour' => $nHour);

}

// your query goes here with result into $aMyQueryResult

foreach ($aMyQueryResult as $aOpensHour){

  $aHours[$aOpensHour['hour']] = $aOpensHour;

}
```

Comment: Straightforward, thank you very much! Everyone else's answer would of worked so +1 for all.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, something like this:

```
$newArray = new array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($yourArray as $opensHour){
  $thiscount = $opensHour['hour'];
  while($thiscount>$count){
     $newArray[] = array("opens"=>0, "hour"=>$count);
     $count++
  }
  $newArray[] = $opensHour;
  $count++; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($resultFromDB as $opensHour){
  $thiscount = $opensHour['hour'];
  while($thiscount>$count){
     $newArray[] = array("opens"=>0, "hour"=>$count);
     $count++;
  }
  $newArray[] = $opensHour;
  $count++; 
}
while ($count < 24) {
    $newArray[] = array("opens"=>0, "hour"=>$count);
     $count++;
}
```

Adapted from @Nanne's solution to fill in missing hours up to 23.